# Правильная ли это структура проекта Django?

Tags: python, django

Решил изучить Django, нашел курс, и в ходе создания проекта через команду

```
django-admin startapp lesson1
```

Заметил что структура проекта у меня отличается от показанного в курсе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в интернета и на metanit, у которого одна у та же версия Django выдает другую структуру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поискав в интернете, не нашел такой проблемы, может я что то неправильно делаю или это вовсе не проблема?

Comment: Структура со второго скриншота создаётся командой startproject, не путайте её со startapp

Comment: ага, спасибо, понял проблему, а можете объяснить либо кинуть статью где разъясняются отличия?